# Raspberry pi live video Object detection

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, object-detection

I am new to using python and object detection and need some help for a uni project!

1- I am wandering if it is possible to use the same haar cascade file i used to train the pi to detect a specific object in a still image (using the picamera) for detecting the same image in a live video feed as my uni project requires the robot to search and find the specific object and retrieve it or do is it a completely separate process (i.e. setting up classes etc)? if so, where could I i find the most helpful information on doing this as I haven't been too successful when looking online. (pyimagesearch has a blog post on this but goes about using classes and i'm not sure how to go about even creating a class just for a specific object or if you even need one..)

2- Currently, my pi can kind of detect the object (a specific cube) in the still images but isnt very accurate or consistent, it often detects around the edges of the object as well as incorrectly detecting other things in the background or shadows that are part of the image, as the object as well. It tends to find more than one of the cube (lots of small rectangles mostly around - in close proximity) and in the object so it says its detecting 2+ cubes in an image (sometimes 15-20 or more) rather than just the one cube. I am wandering how I could reduce this error and increase the accuracy and consistency of the pi so it detects just the one, or at least doesn't wrongfully detect background shadows or other things in the image? I understand that lighting affects the result but I am wandering if its due to the quality of the original image i took with the picamera of the cube I used to train the haar cascade (it was quite a dark photo due to insufficient lighting), or maybe the size of the image itself (cropped it down to the edges so it is just the cube and resized it to 50x50), or maybe that I didnt train more than one image of the object against negatives when training the cascade file..? do the images you supply for training the pi have to taken with the picamera or could you take clearer pictures say with your phone and use them to train the cascade for detection via the picamera?I tried upgrading the resolution in the code but that made the data analysis take too long and didnt make much difference. Apologies for the long post as I am new to all this and wandering if theres any way to improve the results or is the only way for higher accuracy to retrain the cascade which I'd rather not do as it took two days to complete due to working with a pi zero W board!

Much Appreciated!

My specs: A raspberry pi Zero W board with a 16gb SD Card on Mac, running openCV 3.2 and Python 2.7.

Code for object detection in an image taken using the pi camera:

```
import io 
import picamera 
import cv2 
import numpy as np

stream = io.BytesIO()

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera: camera.resolution = (320, 240) camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')

buff = numpy.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=numpy.uint8)

image = cv2.imdecode(buff, 1)

cube_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/data/cube1-cascade-10stages.xml')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Cube = cube_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)

print "Found "+str(len(Cube))+" cube(s)"

for (x,y,w,h) in Cube: cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,255,0), 2)

cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',image)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your question (specially the code), please.

Comment: 1 - Why won't you try for yourself, don't see why wouldn't it work except for performance issues. 2 - how many good and bad (different!) samples did you use to train your cascade?

Comment: retrain your haar detector and add all the false positives as negative samples. collect more data. retrain. collect more data. retrain. ...

Comment: I think it depends a lot on the picamera. Try to capture new samples directly with the camera, and redo the train